# how to prevent bubbling event when use Turbolinks.visit(path)

Tags: javascript, jquery, turbolinks

I use aspnetmvcturbolinks in own project and I have reload page with
Turbolinks.visit(path) when user add text in input . but,when page changed I check this keyup event of input is fire more one and I add return false but not work .

```
$(document).on("ready page:load", function() {
        $('input[name=keyword]').keyup(function (e) {
            alert();
            var $text = $(this).val();
            if ($text.length > 1) {
                $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 600, function() {
                    Turbolinks.visit('@searchUrl' + '?keyword=' + $text);
                });
            }
            if ($text.length == 0) {
                Turbolinks.visit('@searchUrl');
            }
          return false;
        });
        $(document).on('change', 'select[name="order"]', function() {
            Turbolinks.visit('@searchUrl');
        });
        $(document).on('change', 'select[name="count"]', function() {
            Turbolinks.visit('@searchUrl');
        });
    });
```

what is solution?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
e.stopPropagation();
```

instead of

`return false;`

http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/

Comment: problem solved with 
                e.preventBubble(); thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try This,

if(e.stopPropagation)e.stopPropagation();

else e.cancelBubble=true; // where e is an event object

```
$('input[name=keyword]').keyup(function (e) {
            alert();
            var $text = $(this).val();
            if ($text.length > 1) {
                $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 600, function() {
                    Turbolinks.visit('@searchUrl' + '?keyword=' + $text);
                });
            }
            if ($text.length == 0) {
                Turbolinks.visit('@searchUrl');
                }
           if(e.stopPropagation)e.stopPropagation();
           else e.cancelBubble=true;
});
```

Comment: when use Turbolinks.visit('@searchUrl' + '?keyword=' + $text) , the  if(e.stopPropagation)e.stopPropagation();
           else e.cancelBubble=true; not execute

Comment: problem solved with 
                e.preventBubble(); thanks